# Intellij live template to convert variable to constant

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to make a live template in intellij to convert the following examples into constants, given that I select the input line.

**Examples Inputs:**

```
String houseName = "The big house"
```

```
int houseNumber = 1
```

**Intended results:** (and ideally at the top of the class)

```
public static final String HOUSE_NAME = "The big house"
```

```
public static final int HOUSE_NUMBER = 1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for the ['Extract Constant'](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/extract-constant-refactoring-dialog.html) refactoring dialog (`Ctrl+Alt+C` while on variable declaration).

It gives you options to rename your variable and moves the declaration to the top of the class automatically.